# Formatting JSON data for Tree Graph

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, algorithm

I have a JSON array of the following format (this data is pulled from mongodb to be displayed as a tree graph on a react-based front-end):

```
[
  {
    "name": "7654321",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "LjYgocn9PsHhEFbM7",
        "accountId": "4343213"
      },
      {
        "_id": "sB2ipCstYnLnHrAuu",
        "accountId": "4343271"
      },
      {
        "_id": "JhugmhxS7A57Y34wM",
        "accountId": "4343276"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "4343213",
    "children": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "4343271",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "sie9mtttgdRw7Ktma",
        "accountId": "4343279"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "4343279",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "sie23mtttgdRw7Ktma",
        "accountId": "8765345"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "4343276",
    "children": [

    ]
  }
]
```

The goal is to re-format (rename and delete some keys) this data to be used in [react-tree-graph](https://github.com/jpb12/react-tree-graph). From the sample above, output should look like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "7654321",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "4343213"
      },
      {
        "name": "4343271",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "4343279",
            "children": [
                {
                  "name": "8765345"
                }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "4343276"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you post the snippet which you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first create a `Map` that has as keys the `name` property values, and as corresponding values the (unfinished) result objects. They start off with just the `name` property.

Then you can iterate the `children` information in the input, to wire the `children` into the above mentioned result objects, which can be done efficiently using the `name` as key in the `Map`.

Whenever you wire a child object into a parent object, you know that child is not a top-level object in the final result. So starting with *all* nodes, you would trim that list (a `Set`) all those nodes that occur in a `children` array. This will leave you with only the top level nodes, which in its array form represents the desired output.

Implementation:

```js
let data = [{"name": "7654321","children": [{"_id": "LjYgocn9PsHhEFbM7","accountId": "4343213"},{"_id": "sB2ipCstYnLnHrAuu","accountId": "4343271"},{"_id": "JhugmhxS7A57Y34wM","accountId": "4343276"}]},{"name": "4343213","children": []},{"name": "4343271","children": [{"_id": "sie9mtttgdRw7Ktma","accountId": "4343279"}]},{"name": "4343279","children": [{"_id": "sie23mtttgdRw7Ktma","accountId": "8765345"}]},{"name": "4343276","children": []}];

let map = new Map(data.map(({name, children}) => [name, { name }]));
let roots = new Set(map.values());
for (let {name, children} of data) {
    if (!children?.length) continue;
    map.get(name).children = children.map(({accountId}) => {
        let child = map.get(accountId) || { name: accountId };
        roots.delete(child);
        return child;
    });
}
let result = Array.from(roots);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow! Splendid, your explanation is very clear and well understood. Thank you @trincot.